# Ajuda em relação a posição

Tags: html5, css3

Eu, depois de muito tempo pesquisando, peguei um interesse imenso em relação a desenvolvimento web e quis começar a montar um site eu mesmo. Fiz um layout pelo photoshop e como meu conhecimento em HTML5 e CSS3 é quase nulo, eu resolvi estudar através de vídeos no youtube e sites de duvidas.

Eu estou construindo esse site através de tentativa e erro encima de um exemplo feito com flex visto no youtube, só que eu estou com problemas em relação a posição tanto da logo como as redes sociais e, estou procurando uma forma de posicionar a logo um pouco mais próximo do menu e fazer com que a mesma fique por cima do header, fazendo com que a logo junto com a elipse apareça um pouco mais abaixo, não ficando dentro e aumentando o tamanho do header.

A primeira imagem é, atualmente, meu objetivo

Já a segunda é o problema que to enfrentando agora.

[image: Aqui é como eu to tentando fazer]

[image: E essa é o problema que eu estou enfrentando agora]

```css
*{margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; font-family: 'Opens Sans', sans-serif ;}
nav, ul {list-style: none;}
a {text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0.9;}
a:hover {opacity: 1;} 


header {background-color: #006690; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; display: flex; justify-content: space-around; align-items: center; padding: 20px 50px;}
header img {width: 200px; margin-left: 25%;}
header nav {display: flex}
header li a {color: white;}
header li {margin: 0 50px;}
header li:first-child {margin-left: 0;}
header li:last-child {margin-right: 0;}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
    header {flex-direction: column;}
    header img {margin-bottom: 15px;}
}

header li a {font-size: 30px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Suporte Digital - Segurança e Controle de acesso</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Empresa especializada em Segurança e Controle de Acesso">
        <meta name="keywords"  content="Segurança, Controle de Acesso, Câmeras, Portões Eletronicos">
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
        <meta name="author" content="Kaik Bastos">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="icon" href="./img/Icone.png">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b18bc99c07.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <a href="#"><img src="./img/logo.png" alt="Suporte Digital"></a>
            <nav>
                <li><a href="">Início</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contato</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Loja</a></li>
            </nav>
            <div class="">
            <a href="#"><h1><i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-2x" style="color: white;"></i></h1></a>
            <a href="#"><h1><i class="fab fa-instagram-square fa-2x" style="color: white;"></i></h1></a>
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bom, aparentemente você pode regular isso na margem... Esse tipo de ajuste você tem de ir regulando conforme sua vontade. Você já sabe debugar utilizando as ferramentas do navegador?

Comment: Não, como eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: Qual navegador usa?

Comment: No momento, chrome

Comment: Cltr + Shift + J aí se começa a inspecionar os elementos, ver quais os estilos estão sendo aplicados... Vou votar para fechar a questão, pois não está muito claro o que realmente deseja(em termos técnicos). Existem várias formas para controlar essas medidas, precisa ser mais específico